# call volume increases by iteslf?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, volume

The volume of the call increases by itself when I'm using headphones. It starts at max when a call is coming and a minute or so after I lower it it increases again to the max.
I thought it was my headphones, but it happens with different ones. The volume button also looks fine. And besides, this increase doesn't happen immediately after I lower the volume (which I would expect if something was constantly pressing a button)
I tried to look for a setting that does that, but couldn't find any.
I have Galaxy S5 with stock 5.0 ROM

Answer (score -1):

First try to disable the equalizer of your music player. The Call Ring, Music volume and Alarm has different sound settings. So, check if all the settings are set to minimum volume. And if that doesn't solve your problem, install the [Volume Limit & Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.frizzware.volumelock&hl=en) app from google play-store.

Comment: No equalizer (I use Mort player), the sound setting I'm referring to is Call volume. I sett it to minimum and it goes back to maximum. I prefer to not install an app that would disable my volume adjustment. Also, the phenomena I describe happens when the display is on, so not sure if the app would help